# Visual Studio C++ solution with mixed MT and MD libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, dynamic-linking, lib

I have a Visual Studio C++ that includes a couple of projects and libs.

One is compiled with the MD option, the other one is compiled with the MT option.

Is there any way to make this kind of setup working?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Now that you know the answer, which is probably useless to you, consider asking a different question. Also read [ask].

Comment: You must be fun at parties :)

Comment: The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905649/16764520) might provide some methods but it is a big pain.

Comment: Oh. o_o 
I didn't know you wanted to smalltalk, I thought you had some programming challenge to master... But indeed, I forgot this: ;-)

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? Consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.

Answer (score 1):

A single binary (dll/ exe) should not be compiled with /MD and /MT

The libraries have different code to cope with threads starting and stopping, and even if you get the compile working, it won't necessarily work

Use Dlls to separate the different styles, or make them all consistent