# How to use library compiled with /MD in a project compiled with /MT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, mfc, lib

I am trying to use a third-party .lib compiled with `/MD` in a Visual Studio project that needs to link MFC through a static library, which means it has to be compiled with `/MT`. I have no source code for this third-party library.

Can I somehow modify/recreate/rewrap this library without its source code such that it works with my project, or otherwise somehow alter my project to accept this library?

Comment: This [appears to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469841/10871073). (Or, at best, very tricky.)

Comment: The consensus for more than a decade has been: Don't use `/MT`. Ever. It does not solve even a single problem without creating one. `/MD` is the (only) sane option.

Comment: In the Debug Version, the Standard is MT, shall we change it to MD and copy the needed DLL's to the target machine with _D dll's?